# Xcode 8 SiriKit Extension - Could not attach to pid

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode8-beta4, sirikit

Almost every time I try to run my SiriKit Extension, I get "Sorry, you'll need to continue in the app" along with "Could not attach to pid : '####'" on Xcode. I have Siri capability enabled. Weirdly, 1 out of 10 times when I clean and rebuild, the extension works. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Edit:
In console.app I'm getting this:

```
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(PlugInKit)[12442] <Info>: preparing plug-in <private>(<private>)
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(PlugInKit)[12442] <Notice>: connection to plug-in <private>(0DDA43D4-A588-4478-8405-C219EAA7F591) lost
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(PlugInKit)[12442] <Error>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension}
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(PlugInKit)[12442] <Info>: beginUsing of 0DDA43D4-A588-4478-8405-C219EAA7F591 concludes with error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension}
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(Foundation)[12442] <Notice>: PlugInKit error in beginUsing:
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd[12442] <Error>: __52-[ADExtensionService handleCommand:forDomain:reply:]_block_invoke_2.154 Error with extension request Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension}
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd(Foundation)[12442] <Notice>: killing invalid plugIn
Aug 15 11:43:43 iPhone assistantd[12442] <Error>: -[ADCommandCenter _handleServiceReply:error:forCommand:] Handling service error Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1301 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1005d1eb0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.appID.SiriKitExtension}}} for command <private>
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue when adding NotificationServiceExtension. "Could not attach to pid : '####'" on Xcode. Any initiative will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem after weeks of debugging.

My problem was that SiriKit was running on armv7 architecture. Changing it to arm64 or the default setting of armv7 + arm64 will fix this problem.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Fixed on xCode 8.2.1 for me on action extensions. As default Xcode creates just with arm7, adding arm64 fixing on running on device.